# What's the status of the libc++ port to windows?

Tags: c++, windows, clang, libstdc++, libc++

I've read that you can use Clang on Windows for C++ apps while using the MS implementation of the C++ standard library. But if you want to use libc++ on Windows, you currently need to use something like cygwin or mingw. I also saw some old posts indicating there was an effort to port libc++ to windows but I could not find any info on the status of this effort.

Any info on similar efforts/projects is also appreciated.

Comment: https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/BuildingLibcxx.html

Comment: Thanks! The link mentions experimental support for windows - have you read any feedback about how well it works? issues discovered etc?

Comment: I would love to know as well, I'd rather use libc++ across all platforms.